# Linux Get Permission Denied On sudo xclip -b <filepath

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to copy all data inside the file (stored in `var/lib/docker/volumes/...`), but always get an error "**Permission Denied**". I have used `xclip -b <filepath` to copy file. OS Ubuntu 18 server edition.

Answer (score 1):

Your command consists of two parts: `xclip -b` and `<filepath`.

- The former (`xclip -b`) is calling an executable to copy stuff from the stdin to the clipboard.
- The latter (`<filepath`) redirects the content of a file to the `stdin` of the first part.

Both parts are executed by the shell you are running (as user).

Now when you enhance your command to `sudo xclip -b <filepath` the two parts are:

- `sudo xclip -b`: copying the `stdin` to the superuser's(?) X-clipboard
- `<filename`: redirect (as the user who is owning the shell) the content of a file to the first part.

This is not what you want. What you want is:

- Copy the `stdin` to the **users's** X-clipboard (so `xclip` should **not** be run via `sudo`, but just *as is*).
- Read the file as superuser (so we need some way to tell the shell to apply `sudo` to the reading).

The simplest way to do this is:

```
sudo cat filepath | xclip -b
```

Comment: Error: Can't open display: (null)